# Geometry field issue with MariaDB and PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb, geometry

From a PHP script, using mysqli prepared statement to INSERT a row, I'm getting an error returned from MariaDB on a field of type POINT. Code looks a something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO reports (location) VALUES (?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $variable);
$variable = 'POINT(10,10)';
$stmt->execute();
```

`location` is intended to store GPS co-ordinates and is defined as **point** data type in it's column definition. The error which is returned in the resulting stmt object has **errno = 1416 error = Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field.**

Other columns of varchar type work without issue, so I'm guessing it is somewhere in the underlying table definition being *POINT* data type and the presentation of the intended data *POINT (10, 10)* as a string type in the prepared statement. I had initially thought about just storing lat, lon as individual DECIMAL columns but the POINT data type may serve future purposes much better.

In the MariaDB monitor, the statement:

```
INSERT INTO reports (location) VALUES (POINT(10,10));
```

will work fine and insert the row into the database table.

Also, if I were to use *mysqli_query* (which I don't intend using) as follows;

```
$variable = 'POINT(20, 20)';
$sql = "INSERT INTO reports (location) VALUES ($variable)";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)
```

it works as intended.

So, my query is how in PHP, to replicate the working MariaDB monitor statement or mysqli_query() example via a mysqli prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

`POINT` isn't a string, it's an SQL function. MariaDB isn't smart enough to convert strings to SQL, so you cannot bind it as a string. You can bind the parameters of `POINT` but not the SQL itself.

The following should work fine:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO reports (location) VALUES (POINT(?,?))';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([10,10]);
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works. Ironically, I began coding along those lines originally but got an error (something to do with number of parameters/fields) which I erroneously mistook for a 'this is not going to work so better refactor your code). Refactored the code and arrived at the problem posted.  Many thanks for your answer.